# Proving conservation of mass for linear advection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Reading through some course notes about conservation of mass in linear advection approximation schemes, given $\phi(x, t) \in \mathbb{R}$ and is defined for $0 \leq x < 1$ with periodic boundary conditions, and given mass $M = \int_0^1{\phi dx}$ the proof begins as follows:

$$\frac{dM}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^1 \phi dx = \int_0^1 {\frac{d\phi}{dt} dx} $$

A couple of questions:

1. How can we justify moving $\frac{d}{dt}$ inside the integral?
2. Shouldn't this now be a partial differential $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$ since $\phi$ is a function of space ($x$) and time ($t$)?

The proof continues:
$$-u \int_0^1\frac{d\phi}{dx}dx = -u \int_0^1 d \phi = -u \left[ \phi \right]_0^1 = 0$$
since $\phi(0, t) = \phi(1, t) \forall t$ due to the periodic boundary.

Comment: Is $\phi$ continuous ?

Comment: @Amr Yes, we can assume $\phi$ is continuous

Comment: the condition `$$\fi$$` is in `C^1` is a sufficient condition to bring the derivate into the integral... on the point 2) I agree with you.

Comment: @Jekyll I've clarified that $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$.  Can you give me some intuition to explain why this can be done?

Comment: @hertzsprung I am sorry, I meant is $\phi'$ continuous or at least bouneded

Comment: @hertzsprung class C^1 means that it is continuous and its derivate is continuous. Nothing to do with complex numbers.

Comment: Also, by $phi'$ I meant $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$

Comment: Ah, I wasn't familiar with that notation.  Yes, let's assume that the function and its spatial derivative is continuous (out of curiosity, how does this affect your answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi: [0,1]\times [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$, $(x,t)\mapsto \varphi(x,t)$ is continuous on $[0,1]\times [a,b]$ with its partial derivative $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)$, then $M=M(t)$ is differentiable and

$$\frac{dM}{dt}(t)=\int_0^1\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)dx. $$

The proof uses the  Mean value theorem and the fact that any continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is *ivi* uniformly continuous. Sketchy:

$$\frac{M(t+h)-M(t)}{h}=\int_0^1\frac{\phi(x,t+h)-\phi(x,t)}{h}dx=
\int_0^1\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)dx+
\int_0^1\left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t+\theta h)-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)\right]dx,$$

with $0<\theta<1$. In the second equality  we added and subtracted the terms  $\int_0^1\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)dx$ (which exist as the $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)$ is supposed to be continuous) and we used the [Mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) on the term with the ratio $\frac{\phi(x,t+h)-\phi(x,t)}{h}$.

We go on; as $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)$ is  continuous on $[0,1]\times [a,b]$ which is compact in $\mathbb R^2$, it follows by the [Heine-Cantor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem) that it is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]\times [a,b]$, i.e.

$$\forall \epsilon>0~\exists\delta=\delta(\epsilon):~|(t+\theta h)-t|<\delta\Rightarrow |\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t+\theta h)-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)|<\epsilon.$$

Uniformly continuity implies that the above $\delta$ is a function of $\epsilon$ alone (this is not true in general for continuous functions). In summary we arrive at

$$\big|\frac{M(t+h)-M(t)}{h}-\int_0^1\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)dx|\leq 
\int_0^1|\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t+\theta h)-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,t)|dx\leq \underbrace{\epsilon(1-0)}_{\text{here we used the unif. continuity}}=\epsilon,$$

for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: I'd love to mark this as accepted, but I'm not sure what the policy is for accepting an answer you don't properly understand! :)

Comment: You should note accept it then :-) I would like to make it more understandable, though: which are the parts you would like to extend?

Comment: I have edited my answer.